# Change color of myLocationButton -- Google Maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-api

Is there a way to change the default color of the myLocationButton in Google's APIs for iOS/Android? Can't seem to figure out how to do so.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
    body: _initialPosition == null
        ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
            ),
          )
        : Stack(children: [
            GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: _currentPosition,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _setStyle(controller);
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              markers: _markers,
              polylines: _polylines,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              mapToolbarEnabled: true,
            ),
          ]));
  }
```

Comment: have you tried a custom FloatingActionButton?

Comment: Do you want to change to locationButton itself or the blue dot of your actual location?